# Is it possible to define template files for the context-menu?

Tags: macos, finder, file, shortcut-menu, template

I often have to generate files (for example letters), which should have a certain content at the beginning (e.g. letter head,...). In Many Linux-Distributions there is a folder called `~/Templates` - Every file in this folder appears in the context-menu/"File new" and is copied to the folder after selecting this entry.

Is something like this also possible in MacOSX 10.6.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent user or system wide feature in Mac OS X 10.6.

However, many applications support **Stationery Pad** documents. These are documents marked as read only and when opened create a new untitled document using the original document's content.

The Stationery Pad option is available in the Finder > Get Info panel:

[image: Finder, Stationery Pad checkbox]

tuts+ has a tutorial explaining [how Stationery Pads can be created and used](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-creating-and-using-stationery-pad-templates-in-os-x--mac-31777).

Comment: Quite complicated. I also don't understand the advantage of just copying the file. I need to go to the folder and move the automatically generated file, anyway. As it says in the blog article you posted "I wish Finder would ask you to rename the file from the outset, and also ask where you would like to save it."

Comment: @R_User the implementation of Stationery Pads has not aged well with Mac OS X. It is a not feature Apple have spent much attention on recently but it is the closest to a system wide templating system on Mac.